# scanner is showing error mesege

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, sane

My scanner is detected by'sane-find-scanner'. But frontend version of sane (Simple scan) gives me error message as "Failed to open device; 'genesys:libsub:003:002':invalid argument"
How to resolve this issue of scamnner?

Answer (score 0):

Please try >`sudo strace -o strace.out -f scanimage -T`
it may help..

Comment: please run sudo strace -f scanimage -T to check again

Comment: The final line is sayiny as: 7fd496730000-7fd496746000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 2614386                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-sm3840.so.1.0.25Aborted (core dumped)

Comment: scanimage -L
device `genesys:libusb:003:002' is a Hewlett Packard ScanJet 2400c flatbed scanner

Comment: sudo strace -o strace.out -f scanimage -T 
scanimage: open of device genesys:libusb:003:002 failed: Invalid argument